# inserting row into sqlite3 database from play 2.3/anorm: exception being thrown non-deterministically

Tags: jdbc, sqlite, playframework-2.3

I have a simple web application based on the Play Framework 2.3 (scala), which currently uses sqlite3 for the database. I'm sometimes, but not always, getting exceptions caused by inserting rows into the DB:

```
java.sql.SQLException: statement is not executing
  at org.sqlite.Stmt.checkOpen(Stmt.java:49) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar:na]
  at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.executeQuery(PrepStmt.java:70) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar:na]
  ...
```

The problem occurs in a few different contexts, all originating from SQL(statement).executeInsert()

For example:

```
val statementStr = "insert into session_record (condition_id, participant_id, client_timestamp,   server_timestamp) values (%d,'%s',%d,%d)".format(conditionId,participantId,clientTime,serverTime)

DB.withConnection( implicit c => {
  val ps = SQL(statement)
  val pKey = populatedStatement.executeInsert()
  // ...
}
```

When an exception is *not* thrown, pKey contains an option with the table's auto-incremented primary key. When an exception *is* thrown, the database's state indicate that the basic statement *was* executed, and if I take the logged SQL statement and try it by hand, it also executes without a problem.

Insert statements that aren't executed with "executeInsert" also work. At this point, I could just use ".execute()" and get the max primary key separately, but I'm concerned there might be some deeper problem I'm missing.

Some configuration details:

In application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:database/mySqliteDb.db"
```

My sqlite version is 3.7.13 2012-07-17

The JDBC driver I'm using is "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.7.2" (via build.sbt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue today with the latest driver, and using execute() was the closest thing to a solution I found.

For the sake of completion, the comment on Stmt.java for getGeneratedKeys():

```
/**
 * As SQLite's last_insert_rowid() function is DB-specific not statement
 * specific, this function introduces a race condition if the same
 * connection is used by two threads and both insert.
 * @see java.sql.Statement#getGeneratedKeys()
 */
```

Most certainly confirms that this is a hard to fix bug in the driver, due to SQLite's design, that makes executeInsert() not thread safe.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know. I ended up building a my own little executeInsert-style wrapper based on execute. Not especially pretty, but I didn't see a better option.

Answer (score 0):

First it would be better not to use format for passing parameter to the statement, but using either SQL("INSERT ... {aParam}").on('aParam -> value) or SQL"INSERT ... $value" (with Anorm interpolation). Then if exception is still there I would suggest you to test connection/statement in a plain vanilla standalone Java test app.

Comment: I should have noted that I've tried it with both .on() (that was what I did first) and the format approach above -- they show identical behavior. I thought the latter would be simpler in a snippet.

Comment: Format approach is more than unsafe (allowing SQL injection).Best is to run a standalone test to restrict possible causes, Anorm being DB agnostic, I would say that's an issue specific to SQLLite driver.